# Find $b$ such that $\log_b(x)$ and $\log_b(y)$ are integers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, logarithms

Is it possible to find a value $b$ such that, when given $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$,  $\log_b(x)$ and $\log_b(y)$ result in integers?

My assumption is that if $b\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $b$ may not exist, but what about $b\in\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What about $x=2$ and $y=3$?

Comment: @2000 I'm asking if you could find $b$, given $x,y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$ x = b^{\log_b x} \iff b = x^{1/\log_b x} $$
and dito for $y$. So we must have
$$ x^{1/\log_b x} = y^{1/\log_b y} \iff x^{\log_b y} = y^{\log_b x}  $$
So, for such a $b$ to exist, we must have an integer power of $x$ which equals an integer power of $y$, which is in general wrong, consider for example $x= 2$, $y = 3$.

Comment: Why must we have $x^{1/\log_bx}=y^{1/\log_by}$?

Comment: @SimpleArt As both equal $b$.

Comment: Oh, thanks.  ${}$

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that $x > y$. If $\log_b(x)$ and $\log_b(y)$ are integers, then $\log_b(x/y)$ is too -- in fact it must be a positive number $k$, which means that $b^k = x/y$.

Therefore, if you want $b$ to be a natural number, then $x/y$ must be a natural number, too, and one whose prime factorization has every prime factor that appears in it occurring the same number of times.

Comment: Ah, of course.  I will delete the third paragraph.